# Cannot load a class in different package

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to access a class which is in another package but it does not work. It keeps telling me `ClassNotFoundException`.
When I invoke the `Class.forName("x.testClazz")` with a class in the same package as the `TestGenerator` class it works.

```
package x;
public class TestGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class<?> cls = Class.forName(
                "atv12.randomtesting.integration.classes.EasyBranch");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any Solutions?

Comment: Did you [`import`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) that class from other package?

Comment: Is the `EasyBranch` class on the classpath when running the `TestGenerator`?

Comment: yes i did but does not work!

Comment: Are you sure that `EasyBranch` is in the classpath in `atv12/randomtesting/integration/classes` directory? Does it have correct package declaration? Make sure that `EasyBranch` is compiled.

Comment: Since you can load that class via `Class.forName("full.package.name.of.your.Class")` it seams to be in your classpath. Just to make sure, could you test it with [this code](http://ideone.com/ex3QZG).

Comment: @Pshemo i tested your code and i got same problem.

Comment: i am trying to check the classpath. @PiotrGwiazda can you please tell me how to check it?

Comment: @ajabal: the classpath is what you type right after the `-cp` option when you launch the program using `java -cp ... x.TestGenerator`. How do you launch your program?

Comment: @JBNizet i dont run it using command line. i run using eclips.

Comment: Then open the Debug view, launch the program, right-cick on the node appearing in the Debug view, choose Properties, and examine the startup command. But the classpath should be the one that you configured under Project - Properties - Java Build Path.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to use this code

```
package org.benson.another;
public class TestIt {
public void sayHello(){
    System.out.println("hello");
}
}
```

the TestIt Class is

```
 package org.benson.test;
    import org.benson.another.TestIt;
    public class TestLoadClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        ((TestIt)Class.forName("org.benson.another.TestIt").newInstance()).sayHello();
    }
    }
```

and try to compare what different from your code,maybe you will find the solution